# How to import table in CakePHP Helper?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi i am writing the following code in the ZipcodeClassHelper.php

```
public function get_zip_point($table,$zip) {

  App::import('Model','Driver_location');
  $MyModel = new Driver_location();

  $qry = $MyModel->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('zip'=>$zip)));
  pr($qry); exit;
}
```

I got the error message:

```
Error: Class 'Driver_location' not found
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\2014\cab-zone\cabs\app\View\Helper\ZipcodeClassHelper.php
Line: 25
```

Comment: Try with this 

`App::uses('Driver_location', 'Model');`

Comment: @sismaster coming same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a Model in CakePHP when not inside a Controller can be done like this:

```
$ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
```

Then query the model:

```
$result = $ModelName->find('all');
```

Answer (score 3):

That's violating the MVC pattern, you don't fetch data in the view. Your model is not well named either, it doesn't follow the convention, it should be DriverLocation.

Set your data from the controller to the view:

```
$this->set('whatever', $this->Model->find('...'));
```

Do the blog tutorial to get an idea of how Cake work with it's conventions and MVC.